# How to Start WinAppDriver with HTTPS instead of HTTP

Tags: automation, winappdriver

By default, WinAppDriver can be accessed programmatically by pointing to "http://127.0.0.1:4723/" URL.
But requirement is to run WinAppDriver in such a manner that it can be accessed via "https://127.0.0.1:4723/" instead of "http://127.0.0.1:4723/".
WinAppDriver documentation in GitHub has no mention of any such scenario.
Also, we can see that there is a PFX file in the GitHub project as well:  https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/blob/master/WinAppDriver.pfx (But its use is not clear)